# Unable to access Jupyter Notebook. ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, importerror

I am trying to open Jupyter Notebook in my Windows10 system.
I had python2.7 initially in my machine and I have installed python 3.8.
I have also installed Jupyter Notebook using `pip install Jupyter`

The installation has been successful, but when I try to access Jupyter Notebook, I get this error:

```
C:\Users\abhishek murahari>jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "c:\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq.eventloop import ioloop
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from zmq import backend
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    _ns = select_backend(first)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 28, in select_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the python version you are using is also 32 bit. If not then that could be the issue. You would be using a 64 bit python version.

Comment: I am using 32bit python.